# TryParseExact not parsing with specified format

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm using the following code in linqpad (remove the .Dump() for native C#):

```
string dateTime =   "3/20/2015 1:45:00 PM";
string dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

DateTime timeResult;
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, dateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out timeResult);

parsed.Dump();
timeResult.Dump();
```

However, the parse is `false` and the date is `0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM`.

I can't see any issue in my format string. I tried updating it to `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` with no changing effect.

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the string to ""M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";" with a single h. For that matter, you might as well have to change to h:m:s if your minutes and seconds are in that format too.

Comment: .. You're telling me I've been bashing my brains for a single h? Haha this works - Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, the seconds are double digits in the example so you can't go _that_ far.

Comment: @JeffMercado Hence the 'if' :)